# Customizing source-highlight's color schemes?

Tags: colors, less, syntax-highlighting

The `source-highlight` package is installed on my system. It highlights files I view with less using `/usr/bin/lesspipe` and `LESSOPEN` environment variable.

Now, I want to change the color scheme this mechanism uses for some/all filetypes. I have root on the machine. How do I do this?

Note: It's a Devuan 3 Beowulf (~= Debian 10 Buster) Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use a different style file in the source-highlight that's used for less. In  `/usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh`, you will find:

```
source-highlight --failsafe --infer-lang -f esc --style-file=esc.style -i "$source" ;;
```

you can replace esc.style with a different style file (from `usr/share/source-highlight/`). However... most style files aren't compatible with emitting ANSI escape codes, and won't work. So, you're basically stuck.

Try contacting the author perhaps.

Haven't found anything relevant in the GNU source-highlight manual.

Answer (score 1):

The `esc` default is really bad (version 3.1.8), especially for black terminals because function names are printed as black.

I've spent months trying to figure this out and finally found a good solution. Modify `/usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh` to use the `esc256` built-in style which has bolder colors:

```
source-highlight --failsafe --infer-lang -f esc256 --style-file=esc256.style -i "$source" ;;
```

You can tweak the colors in your own style file, but I found the `esc` -> `esc256` change a big step forward for C++ code that I regularly view in the terminal with `less`.

For selective detection you could use the lesspipe script to detect filetype, then presumably use options like `-s, --src-lang=STRING` to launch source-highlight with a different language style.

Comment: Well, that doesn't really let me customize the scheme, it's just an adjustment of a single, non-customized scheme.

Comment: On my ubuntu installation, the default style files were placed in `/usr/share/source-highlight/`. From there you can copy/paste to a new file and modify. `source-highlight --style-file=/path/to/custom.style --input=<input-file>` will format a file with your new style.